# How to check whether a feature has been activated?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I know I can check the <strike>**installed**</strike> **activated** *(read what Kyle said below)* features of a site via `SPSite.Features`.

I also know I can add or remove a feature via `spSite.Features.Add("featureId")` or `.Remove`.

The question is: How do I check whether a feature is **active**? When querying SPSite.Features, I get all the features for the site, it returns `SPFeature` objects. But I still don't know if the feature is active or not.

Basically I would like to have a bool of `spSite.Features["featureId"].isActive` or something similar.

Comment: Check this link. Hope it will be a help to you http://www.directsharepoint.com/2011/04/programmatically-check-feature-is.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`SPSite.Features` doesn't contain **installed** features.  It contains **activated** features.

To grab a list of all features that are installed, whether activated or not, you need to grab `SPFeatureDefinition` objects from the `SPSite.FeatureDefinitions` property.

```
// Get a list of activated features
SPFeatureCollection features = SPContext.Current.Site.Features;

// Get a list of all feature definitions available
SPFeatureDefinitionCollection featureDefinitions = SPContext.Current.Site.FeatureDefinitions;
```

A better description from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466305.aspx):

```
The presence of a feature in a collection at the farm 
(Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService), Web application
(Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication), site collection
([T:Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite)], or Web site (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb) 
levels indicates that the feature is activated. Lack of an SPFeature object 
indicates that the object is not active in the given scope.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.featuredefinitions.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.features.aspx

Comment: perfect explanation - weird thing is that somehow in Powershell SPSite.Features returns the feature even when I disabled it via the frontend...

Comment: Correction: You need to dispose of the site object after disabling a feature, then it displays the current state of affairs.